# Lagrange multipliers in the context of the calculus of variations

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose we wanted to extremise the function (of a finite number of variables) $f$ subject to the constraint $g = 0$. The Lagrange multiplier approach is to extremise without constraint the function

$$ f(x_1, x_2, \ldots) + \lambda g(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$$

I'm not sure I can completely justify this to myself --- I've come across an intuitive geometrical argument but that is all -- and perhaps this is the problem. Essentially, my intuition would be to extend this to functionals like so: suppose we wanted to extremise the functional $F$ subject to the constraint $G = 0$. Then we should extremise without constraint the functional $F +\lambda G$. For instance, suppose

$$ F = \int L(Q_i) \, dx\,dy $$

Where the $Q_i$ are functions of $x$ and $y$, subject to the constraint

$$ \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{Q} = A(x,y) \,.$$

My approach has been to define the functional

$$G = \int  \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{Q} - A(x,y) \, dx \,dy $$

Which means the constraint can be written as $G = 0$. Then to solve the problem we need to extremise without constraint the functional

$$ F + \lambda G$$

for some Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$. That is, we need to solve

$$ \frac{\delta F}{\delta Q_i} + \lambda \frac{\delta G}{\delta Q_i} = 0$$

for each $i$. However, because of the nature of $G$, its functional derivative is identically zero. This means that my Lagrange multiplier drops completely out of the problem, which can't be right. I have found answers to this question and the approach they take is to treat $\lambda = \lambda(x,y)$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, bringing it inside the integral in the expression for $G$. That is

$$ \mathrm{extremise} \qquad \int L(Q_i) + \lambda\left( \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{Q} - A)\right)\, dx dy$$

I've never seen anything like this before --- I have always treated the Lagrange multiplier as some constant that sits outside the integral. Can anybody explain what is going on?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that you need a Lagrange multiplier for each constraint. For each point $(x,y)$ you get a new constraint, which means that $λ=λ(x,y)$ is a function. See optimal control with PDE constraints.

Comment: Ah thank you, I suddenly see now. The constraint $G = 0$ that I gave is a far weaker constraint than the actual constraint, which says that div Q must equal A _at every point_. This all makes sense, cheers.